# What does Spanier mean by "conjugacy class of isomorphisms"?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

In Chapter 1.7 of Spanier's Algebraic Topology, Spanier writes:

> If $A$
>     and $B$
>     are in the same component of a groupoid, the collection of isomorphisms $\{h_{f}\mid f:A\rightarrow B\}$
>     is a conjugacy class of isomorphisms $hom(A,A)\rightarrow hom(B,B)$.

By ${h_{f}}$ he means the group isomomorphism $hom(A,A)\rightarrow hom(B,B)$ which maps each morphism $g:A\rightarrow A$  to $f\circ g\circ f^{-1}$. I do not understand what he means by "conjugacy class of isomorphisms $hom(A,A)\rightarrow hom(B,B)$". From what I understand, a conjugacy class is a set of the form $\left\{ bab^{-1}\mid b\in G\right\}$ 
  for some $a\in G$ where $G$ is some group. I get that for each object $A$ in the groupoid, $hom(A,A)$ is a group under composition but what I don't get is how the isomorphisms $hom(A,A)\rightarrow hom(B,B)$ are elements of a group related to the groups on the hom sets, so the statement "conjugacy class of isomorphisms $hom(A,A)\rightarrow hom(B,B)$" makes absolutely no sense to me.

Note this question has been asked once before but I didn't feel that the reply was satisfactory.

Comment: A link to the previous version of this question, please?

Comment: And could you clarify why you feel the reply was unsatisfactory? (I presume the previous version was [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425496/conjugacy-class-of-isomorphisms-between-two-isomorphic-groups-definition?rq=1).)

Comment: Yes it was that question, and I thought it was unsatisfactory because the person who replied didn't actually answer the question.